# How to mock window.gapi.load() in jest for vuejs

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, google-authentication, vue-test-utils, google-api-js-client

I have used google auth in my vuejs application. Also I am using vue-test-utils for unit testing.

Problem occurs when I need to mock google auth methods like window.gapi.load(), window.gapi.auth2.init(), etc ...

I tried using jest.fn(), but it didnt work. Also I tried this :

```
window.gapi = {
  load() { }
}
```

Beyond this I couldn't proceed. Also mocking google api's are bit of a grey area. Not much docs are available online.

### Login.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="center login__wrapper">
    <div fluid fill-height login>
      <div id="my-signin2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
export default {
  name: "Login",

 data() {
   return {

   }
 },

 methods: {
   onSuccess(GoogleUser) {
     this.$router.push("/homepage");
  },

   onFailure() {
     console.log("try again)
  },

   renderButton() {
     this.init();
     let self = this;
     window.gapi.signin2.render("my-signin2", {
       scope: "profile email",
       width: 240,
       height: 50,
       longtitle: true,
       theme: "dark",
       onsuccess: this.onSuccess,
       onfailure: this.onFailure
     });
    },

  init() {
   window.gapi.load("auth2", function() {
     window.gapi.auth2.init({
       client_id: xyz,
       ux_mode: "redirect"
     });
    });
   }
  },

 mounted() {
   this.renderButton();
  }
 };
</script>
```

When I run npm run test:unit, should throw no error. 
I need to mock the following methods:

1) window.gapi.load()

2) window.gapi.auth2.init()

3) window.gapi.signin2.render()

4) renderButton()

5) onSuccess(), onFailure()

It becomes more difficult as these methods do not return anything. Please help me out here